# Ajax form omitting first part of the array when sending to mail function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, phpmailer

I have small form which is then submitted via ajax to a mail function. However no matter which way around i order the fields in the form the first field never seems to make it to my mailbox.

The other fields work fine.

Here is my html.

```
<form class="form-horizontal amendmentform" name="amendmentform">                                                                               
<input type="hidden" name="guestname" value="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'guestname', true ); ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="arrival" value="<?php echo $arrivaldate; ?>">
<input type="text" name="message">
<a id="amendmentsubmit"class="btn btn-primary">Send Request</a>                           
</form>
```

When I console.log the data I get the full string for all fields.

My Script
jQuery('#amendmentsubmit').click(function() { 
        var data = jQuery(this).closest('.amendmentform').serialize();

```
        jQuery(function(){
            jQuery.ajax({
                url:"http://www.servicedcitypads.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
                type:'POST',
                data:'action=amendment_form&data=' + data,           
                success:function(result){   
                    jQuery('.amendmentform').hide();                    

                  }
            });
        });

    });
```

And finally my PHP for building the message variable.

```
// Build the message
$message  = "Guestname :" . $_POST['guestname'] ."\n";
$message .= "<br>Arrival Date :" . $_POST['arrival'] ."\n";
$message .= "<br>Amendment :" . $_POST['message'] ."\n";
```

No matter which order I place these in its always the first $_POST that wont make it to my mailbox. Weird.

Thanks for any assitance you may offer.

Comment: Why not assign the form data to jquery variables rather than using standard form functions?

Comment: try changing `'action=amendment_form&data=' + data` to `'action=amendment_form&' + data`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "data" parameter should be more like:

```
data:{
    action: 'amendment_form',
    data: data
}
```

You could also use the submit method, rather than on click:

```
$('.amendmentform').on('submit', function(){ ... });
```

If nothing is working, try printing `$_POST` to the error log. Add this to your wp-config.php file:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
```

And add this to your ajax function:

```
error_log( print_r( $_POST, true ) );
```

Then check in `wp-content/debug.log` to see what is being sent through on post.

You're serialising your data and passing it through to the ajax function, but then not using it. This could be the actual issue. You may need to use:

```
$_POST['data']['fieldname']
```

To access your data.